# In Highcharts, how to make box plot outliers transition from light to dark colors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, boxplot

Is it possible to make the outliers color transition from light to dark? I am using box plot chart from Highcharts and want my outliers to render from light red to dark red. Any outliers above 100k needs to display in a darker red.

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/samwhite/9amz3y7x/1/

```
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'boxplot',
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Boxplots for Buzz'
        },
        credits: {enabled: false},
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: categories,
            title: {
                text: 'Stock Symbol'
            }
        },

        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Buzz'
            },
        },

        plotOptions: {
            boxplot: {
                fillColor: 'red',
                // medianColor: '',
                // stemColor: '',
                // whiskerColor: ''
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Buzz',
            data: box_dat,
            color: 'red',
        }, {
            name: 'Outliers',
            color: 'red',
            type: 'scatter',
            data: outliers,
            marker: {
                fillColor: 'white',
                lineWidth: 1,
                lineColor: 'red'
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: 'Observation: {point.y}'
            }
        }]

    });
```

Comment: look at this example. You have to use zones http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series/color-zones-simple/

Comment: @BernhardBeatus thanks for the response. I tried to used zones with my code but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use zones or color axis, but they only change `point.color`, which, in your case is replaced by `marker.lineColor`. Add the below plugin to allow changing line color by zones.

```
(function(H) {
    H.wrap(H.Point.prototype, 'getZone', function(proceed) {
        proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

        this.options.marker = {
            lineColor: this.color
        };
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sc2hk1b9/

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Comment: I am amazed by your experience with Highchart library. Thank you so much!